# Switch statement breaks menu

Tags: c

I'm trying to use a switch statement to choose between a triangular prism or triangular pyramid. When I choose 1 it tells me the value must be between 1 and 2. When I choose 2 it chooses triangular pyramid and seems to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float tt, menu1, opt1, opt2, opt3, t, opt4;
    int td;
    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%f",&tt);
{
                printf("\nWhat geometrical figure would you like to use for Volume?\n\n");
                printf("1) Triangular Prism\n");
                printf("2) Triangular Pyramid\n");
                printf("User choice: ");
                scanf("%f", &td);
                while (td < 1 || td > 2) {
                    printf("\nUser choice must be between 1 and 2!\n\n");
                    printf("\nWhat geometrical figure would you like to use for Volume?\n\n");
                    printf("1) Triangular Prism\n");
                    printf("2) Triangular Pyramid\n");
                    printf("User choice: ");
                    scanf("%d", &td);
                }
                switch(td) {
                    case 1:
                    printf("Enter a, b, c, and h of the triangular prism in meters\n\n");
                    printf("a ");
                    scanf("%f", &opt1);
                    printf("b ");
                    scanf("%f", &opt2);
                    printf("c ");
                    scanf("%f", &opt3);
                    printf("h ");
                    scanf("%f", &opt4);
                    printf("\nWould you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
                    scanf("%f", &menu1);
                    if (menu1 == 2) {
                        t = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (menu1 < 1 || menu1 > 2) {
                        printf("\n\nUser choice must be between 1 and 2!\n\n");
                        printf("Would you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
                        scanf("%f", &menu1);
                    }
                case 2:
                    printf("Enter a and h of the triangular pyramid\n\n");
                    printf("a ");
                    scanf("%f", &opt1);
                    printf("h ");
                    scanf("%f", &opt2);
                    printf("\nWould you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
                    scanf("%f", &menu1);
                    if (menu1 == 2) {
                        t = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (menu1 < 1 || menu1 > 2) {
                        printf("\n\nUser choice must be between 1 and 2!\n\n");
                        printf("Would you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
                        scanf("%f", &menu1);
                    }

            }
}
            if (tt == 4) {
                printf("Enter the radius of the circle\n\n");
                printf("Radius: ");
                scanf("%f", &opt1);
                printf("\nWould you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
                scanf("%f", &menu1);
                if (menu1 == 2) {
                    t = 0;
                }
                if (menu1 < 1 || menu1 > 2) {
                    printf("\n\nUser choice must be between 1 and 2!\n\n");
                    printf("Would you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
                    scanf("%f", &menu1);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: What does `%f` mean?

Comment: Use `%d` for `int`

Comment: There is a `break` inside the `if (menu1 == 2)` for each case, but if this condition is not met the break never happens.

Comment: That's what it was. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Funny enough, there is not a single question mark in this "question".

Comment: Note: the code is way too complicated. Also avoid repeating code sequences, this is error-prone and confusing. Use functions or /like here) mpve such code to a part of the code which is used by all paths..

Answer (score 1):

You have to be very careful: the formatting codes in `scanf()` must match the type of the address you provide as additional argument:

- `"%f"` is ok for floats like opt1, opt2, etc...
- But for an int you need `"%d"`
- More combinations [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

If there is a mismatch, not only won't you get the right value in you variable (because the floating point encoding of 1 will not be the same as integer 1), but you risk also buffer overflow and memory corruption (if the `sizeof(float)` is larger than `sizeof(int)`).